# How to I transition my Img size as I am scrolling down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am making a project where I have images animating on a screen as I am scrolling down.I have tried animate but it doesnt seem like it is going with the scroll if i constantly keep going up&down.Hope what i provided helps.

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var rep = $(window).scrollTop();

  if (rep > 860) {
    $('.teaimg').fadeIn();
  }
  if (rep < 860) {
    $('.teaimg').fadeOut();
  }
  
});
```

```css
.teaimg {
  background-image: url("leaf.jpg");
  width: 779px;
  height: 439px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<main>
  <div class="laptopbox1">
    <img id="laptop" src="laptop.jpg">
    <div id="screen">
      <p id="text"></p>
      <div class="teaimg"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: have you tried `console.log(rep);` to see if it's returning anything?

Comment: everything works.The fadeIn and out is working now im trying to figure out how to I shrink the image i should have clarified

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `opacity` concept here by adding and removing a class...Using `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()` will give you abrupt effect as its show and hide the element which will also affect the document height and gives fluctuating effect on scroll...

Also use `else` for the else part of the condition...

I have created a example here...

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var rep = $(window).scrollTop();
  if (rep > 150) {
    $('.teaimg').addClass("show");
  } else {
    $('.teaimg').removeClass("show");
  }

});
```

```css
.laptopbox1 {
  margin: 200px 0;
}

.teaimg {
  background-image: url("http://via.placeholder.com/350x150");
  width: 350px;
  height: 150px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all .3s ease;
}

.teaimg.show {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<main>Scroll
  <div class="laptopbox1">
    <div id="screen">
      <p id="text"></p>
      <div class="teaimg"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```